# Can't make javascript object property value update

Tags: javascript, object

Not sure why I can't seem to update a value.
I'm using a file uploader and I need to append an invoice number to the file name, so we don't get duplicate files.

Here is the code:

```
console.log(data.files[0]);
            console.log(data.files[0].name);
            console.log('$("#InvoiceNumber").val() =' + $("#InvoiceNumber").val() + "-" + data.files[0]['name']);
            //here I try to update 
            data.files[0]['name'].value = $("#InvoiceNumber").val() + data.files[0]['name'];
            //have also tried
            // data.files[0]['name'] = $("#InvoiceNumber").val() + data.files[0]['name'];
            //and
            //data.files[0].name = $("#InvoiceNumber").val() + data.files[0].name;

            console.log(data.files[0]);
```

The results from outputting to console are.

[image]

I can't change the file name server side, as duplicates exist.
Anyone know why I can't update that value.
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to do that at the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`File#name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name) property is readonly. There is nothing you can do with it.

Comment: Oh ok so that must be why, gee this makes my life much harder :(
Thanks for the help

Comment: For those that are interested, I solved my problem. When my form is submitted, I grab the file name which was returned from the file upload funciton. Then I appended my invoice number to the file name and use `System.IO.File.Move("oldfilepath+oldfileName", "newfilepath+newfileName");` to rename the file. Then save against the model.
Thanks all for your help :)